# An apparent contradiction based on considering the series of $f(z)$ and relating it to $f(1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I have a function with a relationship between $f(z)$ and $f(1/z)$ that, when interpreted naively using the series for $f$, gives wrong results.  I'm going to give this naive argument in the hopes that someone can point out very clearly where the problem is.  I realize that there are subtle issues of convergence and several implicit assumptions here, but I'm not sure which one fails.

Suppose that I have a function $f$ that is analytic in a neighborhood of $z=0$, so

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n $$

I'm omitting Considering $f(1/z)$, we get

$$ f\left( \frac{1}{z} \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^{-n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^0 f_{-n} z^n $$

The first equality here is a purely symbolic substitution, so I think it is okay.  The second is a bit fishy because it rearranges the terms in the sum, but I think that the uniqueness of the expansion here should make this okay.  (Please point out if this is wrong.)

Now consider a particular case where there is a relationship between $f(z)$ and $f(1/z)$.  A simple example is

$$ f(z) = \left( \frac{1-z}{1+z} \right)^\alpha $$

Assuming we do branch cuts from $\pm 1$ to $\pm \infty$, then this is analytic near zero and has a radius of convergence of $1$.  Now consider that

$$ f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = (-1)^\alpha f(z) $$

(Invoking $(-1)^\alpha$ is slightly fishy here because it is on the branch cut, but we are not using $z=-1$, so this may be okay.)

If we put some of the equations above together, we get

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^0 (-1)^\alpha f_{-n} z^n $$

Now I will equate these series term-by-term.  This is a very fishy operation, but could be justified by saying that both of these expressions could be interpreted as the Laurent series of $f(z)$, and Laurent series are supposed to be unique.  Obviously, equating them gives the result

$$ f_n = (-1)^\alpha f_{-n} $$

for $n \ge 0$, which is clearly wrong because in actuality, for this case, $f_n = 0$ for $n < 0$ and $f_n \ne 0$ for $n \ge 0$.

I've identified a few fishy steps above, and if someone could explain exactly why they fail, or if there is another implicit assumption that I have not considered, that would be great.

Ultimately, my goal in thinking about this was to try to prove whether a different function $f(z)$ was a polynomial (i.e., the series terminates) or not by looking at a relationship with $f(1/z)$.  If anyone has any thoughts on this, please feel free to share them too, but in the meantime, this "contradiction" became interesting in its own right.

Comment: When you have power series that are equal, the coefficients of the same degree are equal. But the term $f_nz^n$ in the first series does not correspond to $(-1)^\alpha f_{-n}z^n$. In the second series the degrees are all $\leq0$. If the equations between series were true, then all $f_nz^n$, for $n>1$ would correspond to terms in the second series that are not present, that are zero. The only terms that appears in both series is $f_0z^0=(-1)^\alpha f_{-0}z^{0}$. For all other terms the equations that you would obtain are $f_n=0$, and $f_{-n}=0$, for $n>0$. (IF the series were equal).

Comment: @minghan I don't think this is the problem.  You can consider all values of $n$ not present in the sum to have a coefficient of 0, which solves this problem (i.e., there is still a contradiction).  I think Ennar has identified the heart of the problem.

Comment: That is what I said, and what you didn't do in your argument.

Comment: @user566930 The whole point is that if you do this (consider terms left out of the series to have a value of zero) then there is a contradiction, because we know that $f_n$ is not zero for $n \ge 0$.  My whole post is about "Why does there appear to be a contradiction here?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You consider Laurent series of $f$ on the punctured disk $0<|z|<1$ and write it as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_nz^n$. Then, it is true that $f(1/z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_nz^{-n}$, but not on the punctured disk, but the annulus $|z|>1$! 
So, even if it is true that $f(1/z) = (-1)^\alpha f(z)$, you can't equate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^0 (-1)^\alpha f_{-n} z^n$ since they don't converge on the same annulus.

Comment: I knew there was a simple explanation.  Thanks!

Comment: @sasquires, you are welcome. Maybe I should have already added this to the answer, but I'll mention it here. Laurent series is unique, but only on an annulus on which function is holomorphic. If you change annulus in a way such that a singularity is in between the new and the original annulus, Laurent series changes. For example, $1/(1-z)$ has the familiar series $\sum z^n$ for $|z|<1$, but on $|z| >1$ Laurent series changes to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{z^n}$. Notice that there is a change precisely because $z_0 = 1$ is a singularity.